# How to melt the multilevel dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**I have a excel file with multilevel data and i need to melt them into a single level column**

[image]

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

df.to_excel('test1.xlsx')

I need the dataframe output to look like below

```
      Geo PC Month  A  B  C Total
             Jan-19
             Feb-19
```

Comment: @jezrael.. bro any help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `pandas.melt?`

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

> This function is useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables (id_vars), while all other columns, considered measured variables (value_vars), are “unpivoted” to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, ‘variable’ and ‘value’.

Comment: its not working bro...since it is a multilevel data